# Replace comma decimal separator with regex without change it in text values

Tags: regex, notepad++

In txt file for example, with Notepad++ for example, I would target and replace the comma when it is used as a decimal separator in numbers surrounded by tabs ; and let it as a comma when it is used in some text.

I found a regex very nice: `(?<=\t\d)*,(?=\d*\t)`

It seems perfectly worked, but not: it does not work where the number ends the field.

See my example below. The regex also targets the first numbers in line 3 and 5.

[image]

But I would it only targets the number fully surrounded by tabs.

Please have you and idea?

Comment: It's hard without markdown sample data and your expected results, but maybe `\t\d+\K,(?=\d+\t)` would work?

Comment: A quantifier applied to a lookaround doesn't make sense as it is a zero-length assertion.

Answer (score 2):

The lookbehind is optional so it will also match the comma in `,`

Notepad uses Boost regex engine, which does not support a quantifier in the lookbehind assertion, so `(?<=\t\d+)` will not work.

Instead, you could match the text and use an alternation to assert either a tab or the start / end of the string fi there can also be single numbers in the line.

```
(?:\t|^)\d+\K,(?=\d+(?:\t|$))
```

The pattern in parts:

- `(?:\t|^)` Match either a tab or assert the start of the string
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `\K,` Forget what is matched so far and match a comma
- `(?=\d+(?:\t|$))` Positive lookahead, assert 1+ digits followed by either a tab or the end of the string to the right

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/48Ixrl/1).

[image]

If there should be mandatory tabs on the left and the right, you can omit the alternations and use the pattern posted by @[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv) in the comments.

Comment: Per-fect! It works on fire!